# React Javascript Arrow and Class makes a Wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was on this website here: https://hackernoon.com/animated-page-transitions-with-react-router-4-reacttransitiongroup-and-animated-1ca17bd97a1a

And I got the solution to work, but I don't fully understand the javascript code.  Specifically, I saw something like this in the `AnimatedWrapper.js` class:

```
const AnimatedWrapper = WrappedComponent => class AnimatedWrapper
 extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 }
}
export default AnimatedWrapper;
```

And then in my `Home.js` file, I can do this

```
class default Home extends Component {/* blah blah blah */}
const Home = new AnimatedWrapper(Home);
export default Home;
```

My question is what is that `const AnimatedWrapper = WrapperComponent => class AnimatedWrapper extends Component` doing?  I was surprised that AnimatedWrapper is expect ONE argument in it's constructor called `props`, which I assume would be something OTHER than the `Home` object that I passed it.

Comment: You are using a Higher Order Component.  Much has been written about them so a quick search should allow you to fully understand how they work.  Calling it with `new` is probably not recommended.  The key here is that `class` in Javascript is a type of `function`.

Comment: ok great, the phrase Higher Order Component gives me something to google for and research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pattern used in react to demonstrate composition. In this case `AnimatedWrapper` is a higher order component.

> A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, per se. They are a pattern that emerges from React’s compositional nature.

You can read more about higher order components below

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

To answer your question, what is the code sample doing ... its doing nothing but rendering another component. At this stage thats its only responsibility, but you may later expect to see logic shared here so it could be made available to other components.

For example, an animated menu `AnimatedWrapper(Menu)` or an animated button `AnimatedWrapper(Button)` - rather then store the animation logic for a menu or button at the child level, it helps to have these wrappers or HOCs hold that responsibility for purposes of reusability.